# can a tag be put into CompletionQueue twice in grpc cpp?

Tags: grpc

can a tag be put into CompletionQueue twice in grpc cpp,

1. if cannot, what's behaviour it will be?
2. if can, does this tag be visit twice or only once in Next function?

note: twice means put another time before this tag be read by any next function

Comment: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_async_reader_writer.html#a07bcc3a0737c3bee3ef50def89af5fc7 this doc said a tag must be read before another write. but I have a situation, I need call WriteDone and Write at same time?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Unique tags allow you to ensure that a specific operation is completed, which is necessary for example to ensure there is at most one outstanding write at any given time.